# Regex Count not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

It keeps going to the else statement for Missing numbers. It reads if I input "The" but when i input two numbers it says the count is still `0`. then will return the else statement instead of going and changing the labels. Why?

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = textbox.Text;
    string s = textbox.ToString();
    input = input.Trim();

    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"\d+");

    string[] result = matches.Cast<Match>()
                                .Take(2)
                                .Select(match => match.Value)
                                .ToArray();

    if (input.StartsWith("The") || input.StartsWith("the"))
    {
        if (matches.Count == 2)
        {
            alarm.Text = result[0];
            server.Text = result[1];
        }
        else
        {
            string script = "alert(\"Missing Number(s)!\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                    "ServerControlScript", script, true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your exact input string?

Comment: You need to replace `string s = textbox.ToString();` with `string s = textbox.Text;`, otherwise you analyze a different string :)

Comment: I do not see the point in using two variables for the text box value. You may just use `input` and only trim it when checking with startswith.

Comment: Looks like you're matching `^[tT]he\D*(?:(\d+)(?:\D+(\d+))?)?` why go through all the agony of what you're doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it. I think this way it's much more cleaner and easier to read:

```
string input = textbox.Text.Trim();

var match = Regex.Match(input, @"^[tT]he\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\b");

if (match.Success && match.Groups.Count == 3)
{
    var alarm = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var server = match.Groups[2].Value;
}
else
{
    string script = "alert(\"Missing Number(s)!\");"; // Or "invalid format".
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
}
```

You didn't say much about that input string, so you may have to tune that regular expression. I supposed you expect spaces between the terms and ignore anything after the second digit.

Answer (score 2):

`Regex.Matches.Count` works correctly.

You need to replace

```
string s = textbox.ToString();
```

with

```
string s = textbox.Text;
```

Else, you analyze a different string (the `textbox` type string).

Also, you can use just one variable for the text box value and trim it when  necessary only.